# Get values from dynamic inputs generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

I am writing a generator for improving my knowledge of PHP programming and handling as I am weak and I already know that I would like to ask how I can make this.
Generate input data in javascript and I want to dynamically capture their value in PHP. I do not know how many of them, because they are generated after clicking the button in, hence the problem.

At the same moment I succeeded in JS up using this name: name_0, name_1 and so on.

Is it feasible? Below I do not

```js
var tytul = document.getElementById("k-title");
var opis = document.getElementById("k-description");
var popup = document.getElementById("info_box");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var podsumowanie = document.getElementById("summary");

$("#add").on("click", function () {
var id = $(".wiersz").length;
$('#tabela').append('<tr class="wiersz"><td class="komorka-lewa"> <input class="cecha" name="cecha_'+ id + '" type="text" placeholder="Cecha produktu"> </td><td class="komorka-prawa"><input class="cecha-opis" name="cecha-opis_'+ id + '" type="text" placeholder="Opis cechy produktu"></td></tr>');
document.getElementById("default-table").style = "display: none";
});

$("#add_square").on("click", function() {
var szerokosc = prompt("Podaj szerokość obrazka");
var wysokosc = prompt("Podaj wysokość obrazka");
var sciezka = prompt("Podaj link do zdjęcia");
$("#other-photos").append('<div class="other-img" style="width: '+szerokosc+'px;"><img class="img-present" style="height: '+ wysokosc +'px;" src="'+sciezka+'" /></div>');

if (szerokosc < 1050) {
$(".other-img").css("float", "left");
}
});

$("#add_photo").on("click", function () {
var sciezka = prompt("Podaj link do zdjęcia");
var opis = prompt("Podaj opis zdjęcia dla wyszukiwarek");
$("#gallery").append('<div class="photo-container"><button class="del">Usuń zdjęcie</button><img src="' + sciezka + '" class="photo" alt="' + opis + '"/></div>');

if ($(".photo").length > 0) {
document.getElementById("default-gallery").style = "display: none";
}
$(".del").on("click", function () {
$(this).parent().css("display", "none");
document.getElementById("default-gallery").style = "display: block";
});
});

$("#gen").on("click", function () {

if (opis.value.length < 1 || tytul.value.length < 1) {
popup.style = "display: block";
overlay.style = "display: block";
document.getElementById("infobox-content").innerHTML = "Uzupełnij wszystkie potrzebne dane, zanim wygenerujesz kartę produktu.";
} else {
popup.style = "display: block";
overlay.style = "display: block";
document.getElementById("infobox-content").innerHTML = "Karta została wygenerowana, plik z kodem znajduje się w katalogu generate.";
podsumowanie.innerHTML = "Tytuł: " + tytul.value + "<br>" + "Opis produktu: " + opis.value + "<br>" + "Cecha produktu: " + cecha +  "<br>" + "Opis cechy produktu: " + cechaopis;
}
});

$("#close").on("click", function() { 
popup.style = "display: none";
overlay.style = "display: none";
});

$("#add_section").on("click", function() {
var szerokosc = prompt("Określ szerokość sekcji");
var wysokosc = prompt("Określ wysokosć sekcji");
var tlo = prompt("Określ kolor tła sekcji (paleta RGB - np. FFFFFF)");
var kolor = prompt("Określ kolor tekstu w sekcji (paleta RGB - np. FFFFFF)");
$("#new_section").append('<div class="sekcja" style="width: '+ szerokosc +'px; height: '+ wysokosc +'px; background: #'+ tlo +'; color: #'+ kolor +';"><button type="button" class="check_btn">Checklista</button><button type="button" class="txt_btn">Sekcja tekstowa</button></div>');

if ($(".sekcja").length > 0) {
$("#default-section").css("display","none"); 
}

if(szerokosc < 1050) {
$(".sekcja").css("float","left"); 
}

});
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: 'open sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}

.wiersz {
background-color: #eee; 
margin: 0;
}

.komorka-lewa {
padding: 3px 10px; 
text-align: right; 
border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.komorka-prawa {
padding: 3px 10px; 
text-align: left;
}

#tabela {
font-size: 14px; 
border: none; 
border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb; 
width: 100%;
}

.cecha, .cecha-opis {
border: 0;
margin: 0;
background: 0;
}

#gen {
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#add, #gen, #add_photo, #add_section {
border: 0;
padding: 10px;
background: #222;
color: #fff; 
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: 'open sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}

#add:hover, #gen:hover, #add_photo:hover, #add_section:hover, .check_btn:hover, .txt_btn:hover {
background: green;
cursor: pointer;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

#add_section {
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#container {
max-width: 1050px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

#overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
}

#info_box {
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
width: 500px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
padding: 10px;
padding-top: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
}

#info_box p:first-child {
font-size: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#info_box, #overlay {
display: none;
}

#info_box > p span {
cursor: pointer;
color: red;
}

.photo {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

.photo:first-child {
margin-top: 25px;
}

.photo:last-child {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#default-gallery, #default-section {
font-size: 14px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
padding: 5px;
}

.photo-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.photo-container:first-child {
margin-top: 25px;
}

.photo-container:last-child {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.del {
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
right: 25px;
background: transparent;
border: 3px solid #fff;
padding: 10px;
font-family: 'open sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.del:hover {
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
color: #222;
}

#add_square {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background: #eaeaea;
margin-bottom: 25px;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

#add_square:hover {
background: #222;
cursor: pointer;
transition-duration: 0.5s; 
color: #fff;
}

.img-present {
max-width: 100%;
}

.other-img:last-child {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.sekcja {
position: relative; 
}

.check_btn, .txt_btn {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border: 0;
background: #000;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: 'open sans',sans-serif;
color: #fff;
}
 
.check_btn {
left: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.txt_btn {
right: 0;
b
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info_box">
<p>Informacja <span id="close" style="float: right;">x</span></p>

<p id="infobox-content"></p>
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="container">

<form method="post" action="">

<div style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
<input type="text" value="" id="k-title" name="k-title" placeholder="Tytuł karty" style="display: block; width: 100%; font-size: 30px; border: 0; background: 0; margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">
<input type="text" value="" id="k-description" name="k-desc" placeholder="Krótki opis" style="display: block; width: 100%; border: 0; background: 0; text-align: justify; padding: 10px;">
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Specyfikacja techniczna</div>

<table id="tabela" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" id="default-table">Brak dodanej specyfikacji</td>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;" id="add" type="button">Dodaj wiersz</button>


<div id="other-photos">
<div id="add_square" style="position: relative;">
<p style="text-align: center; position: absolute; width: 150px; top: 40px; font-size: 60px; margin: 0;">+</p>
<p style="text-align: center; position: absolute; width: 150px; bottom: 40px; margin: 0;">Dodaj obrazek prezentacji</p>
</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Dodaj nową sekcję</div>

<div id="new_section">
<div id="default-section">Brak dodanych sekcji</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Dodaj sekcję</button>

<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Galeria zdjęć</div>
<div id="default-gallery">Brak dodanych zdjęć</div>

<div id="gallery">
</div>

<button style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;" id="add_photo" type="button">Dodaj zdjęcia</button>

<input id="gen" type="submit" value="Generuj kartę" />

</div>

<div id="summary">
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: It would be way more easy to help you, if you could give a brief description of what your site does. My polish is not that good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest Solution:

Name your generated Inputfields like:

```
<input ... name="field[]"> // see the []-Brackets
<input ... name="field[]">
<input ... name="field[]">
```

The Brackets will cause, that there will be sent an Array named "field" when submitting the Form. Of course you can also give them a Key like field[0], field[1] or what ever.

After you submitted the Form you can handle it like any other PHP-Array.

For Example:

```
foreach($_POST['field'] as $fieldno => $fieldvar){
 echo 'field '.$fieldno.': '.$fieldvar.'<br>';
}
```

Tip: Using the same Keys for the same Section is quite helpful for processing trough the Data:

```
<input name="givenname[0]"><input name="lastname[0]"><input name="age[0]">
<input name="givenname[1]"><input name="lastname[1]"><input name="age[1]">
<input name="givenname[2]"><input name="lastname[2]"><input name="age[2]">
```

You can catch these Data after submitting this way:

```
foreach($_POST['givenname'] as $id => $givenname){
 echo 'person #'.$id.': '.$_POST['lastname'][$id].', '.$givenname.', '.$_POST['age'][$id].'<br>';
}
```